# MDX - Concurrent calculations based on a "record time range"?

Tags: olap, mdx

**Dear MDX experts,**

*- Is it possible to get the concurrent calculation based on a record time range?*

***Lets say I have;*** *'start date'*, *'end date'*, *'used'*, and *'color'* available... in my fact table..

Is it possible to get the concurrent of *'used'* per time (the biggest sum of 'used' that happened during the same range), if yes - what about concurrent used per 'color'?

Comment: Should I just do these calculations in the ETL process?

Comment: I'm confused, what does "concurrent" mean in this context, because it doesn't mean what I think you mean.

Comment: "concurrent" as in - want to see the sum of used that happened in the same time period (between start-data and end-data)...

Answer (score 0):

To get the sum of all used over a time period, you can use the [`sum`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms145484.aspx) function.

Moreover, this will take into account the `CurrentMember` of `Color`, so it will be per member, whatever selection you choose.

This MDX is a starting point:

```
with member [Measures].[TotalUsed] as
    sum({[Date].[YQM].&[20090501]:[Date].[YQM].&[20090907]}, [Measures].[Used])

select
    {[Measures].[Total Used]}
on columns,
    {[Color].[Colors].[All].MEMBERS}
on rows
from [Cube]
```

I think this is what you're looking for, but please clarify in comments if it doesn't meet your needs.